# Cipher Block Chaining

Tags: block-cipher, cbc

I don't want the answer to this problem, I just want to understand the steps that need to be followed to solve it. Maybe an example could help.

### Problem

We use $\mathbin\Vert$ for  concatenation.

Let $P_1 \mathbin\Vert P_2$ be a message that is two blocks long, and let $P'_1$ be a message that is
one block long.

Let $C_0 \mathbin\Vert C_1 \mathbin\Vert C_2$ be the encryption of $P_1 \mathbin\Vert P_2$ using CBC mode with a
**random IV** and a **random key**, and let $C'_0 \mathbin\Vert C'_1$ be the encryption of $P'_1$ using CBC
mode with a **random IV** and the **same key**.

Suppose an attacker knows $P_1 \mathbin\Vert P_2$ and
suppose the attacker intercepted and thus know $C_0 \mathbin\Vert C_1 \mathbin\Vert C_2$ and $C'_0 \mathbin\Vert C'_1$.
Further suppose that, by random chance, $C'_1=C_2$.

Show that the attacker can compute $P'_1$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem suggests that the encryption does not use padding, and $C_0=\mathit{IV}$, $C_0'=\mathit{IV}'$. Then
$$E_k(C_0\oplus P_1) = C_1$$
$$E_k(C_1\oplus P_2) = C_2$$
$$E_k(C_0'\oplus P_1') = C_1'$$
You also have
$$C_1'=C_2$$
That is enough to find $P_1'$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
E_k(P_1'\oplus C_0')&=&C_1'\\
P_1'\oplus C_0'&=& E_k^{-1}(C_1')\\
P_1'&=&E_k^{-1}(C_1')\oplus C_0'\\ 
P_1'&=& E_k^{-1}(E_k(C_1\oplus P_2))\oplus C_0' \because C_1'=C_2=E_k(C_1\oplus P_2)\\
P_1'&=&C_1\oplus P_2 \oplus C_0'
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I guess you missed "I don't want the answer to this problem, I just want to understand the steps that need to be followed to solve it."